# django-registration, registration and login form on index page together, did I do it right?

Tags: django, django-views, django-registration

I'd appreciate some code review, I used django-registration app and django.contrib.auth module. What I wanted to do is have both the login and registration form on the index page, and manage it from there. What I did is I just copied code from registration.views.py and contrib.auth.views.py and banged it together.

It works but I feel it's very hack-ish, non elegant, and that there is another, proper way to do it. For example I feel it might be better to call or extend view methods in registration and auth instead of copy pasting them.

```
def index(request, success_url=None,
             form_class=RegistrationForm,
             authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
             profile_callback=None,
             template_name='index.html',
             extra_context=None, **kwargs):

    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        form_auth = authentication_form(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(profile_callback=profile_callback)
            # success_url needs to be dynamically generated here; setting a
            # a default value using reverse() will cause circular-import
            # problems with the default URLConf for this application, which
            # imports this file.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url or reverse('registration_complete'))

        if form_auth.is_valid():
            netloc = urlparse.urlparse(redirect_to)[1]

            # Use default setting if redirect_to is empty
            if not redirect_to:
                #redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
                redirect_to = "/"

            # Security check -- don't allow redirection to a different
            # host.
            elif netloc and netloc != request.get_host():
                #redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
                redirect_to = "/"

            # Okay, security checks complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form_auth.get_user())

            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

    else:
        form = form_class()
        form_auth = authentication_form()


    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value
    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              { 'form': form, 'form_auth': form_auth},
                              context_instance=context)
```

And forms in the index.html:

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="errors">Please correct the errors below: {{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    {% endif %}

    <h3>Create an account</h3>

    <form method="post" action="" class="wide">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
          <label for="id_username">Your Username:</label>
          {% if form.username.errors %}
            <p class="errors">{{ form.username.errors.as_text }}</p>
          {% endif %}
          {{ form.username }}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_email">Email address:</label>
          {% if form.email.errors %}
            <p class="errors">{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</p>
          {% endif %}
          {{ form.email }}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_password1">Password:</label>
          {% if form.password1.errors %}
            <p class="errors">{{ form.password1.errors.as_text }}</p>
          {% endif %}
          {{ form.password1 }}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="id_password2">Password (type again to catch typos):</label>
          {% if form.password2.errors %}
            <p class="errors">{{ form.password2.errors.as_text }}</p>
          {% endif %}
          {{ form.password2 }}
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
    </form>

    {% if form_auth.errors %}
    <p class="error">Please correct the errors below:</p>
    {% endif %}


    <h3>Log in</h3>

    <form method="post" action="?next={{ next|default:"/" }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <dl>
    <dt><label for="id_username">Username:</label>{% if form.username.errors %} <span class="error">{{ form.username.errors|join:", " }}</span>{% endif %}</dt>
    <dd>{{ form_auth.username }}</dd>
    <dt><label for="id_password">Password:</label>{% if form.password.errors %} <span class="error">{{ form.password.errors|join:", " }}</span>{% endif %}</dt>
    <dd>{{ form_auth.password }}</dd>
    <dt><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></dt>
    </dl>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite natural to place login or registration form at index page (or on every page), but why do you need to process the forms there? Process login on `/auth/login/`, process registration on `/auth/registration/` and your code will be clean and extendable.

Comment: Thanks for advice, this seem like a good way to do it. I just don't know how to do that in my views or template code.