# how to set django root url as login url?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

when using django-registration , the url confuse me a bit

say i want my inidex page localhost:8000 to be a login page, but the django-registration's login url has a /login prefix, do i have to put the /login in my url like

```
url(r'^/login/$', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

in this case , the localhost:8000 will be empty, dose it mean after deploy this project ,view the url like something.com will be empty.

how to set the index page to be a actual django-registration login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not really, you need to include the @login_required decorator on the views that you want the user to be authenticated, for eg.

```
# views.py

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Only registers will see this page')

# now you can add the stuff that you would want only the registered users to view, 
# so basically if a new visitors tries to visit your site say at www.abc.com, he will first be redirected to the www.abc.com/login/ where he needs to create an account, once authenticated, he will then be redirected to the index page
```

Reference [django-registration, registration and login form on index page together, did I do it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761626/django-registration-registration-and-login-form-on-index-page-together-did-i-d)

Comment: so you mean my url actually point to say profile page, but that requires login , so the viewer will first be redirect to url/login page right? i used to do this, but is it the only way to do this? i mean what is the url(r'^$') should point to?

Comment: it should be pointing to r'^/login/$' since you need to, process login on 'login/, process registration on /registration/ and your code will be clean and extendable.

Comment: that should be the index page or the homepage of the site, it should be handled by one of your views, if you need the users to be registered to view that page, just add the @login_required decorator and the users will be redirected to /login/ page before they can view your index page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know that it is the best way of going about it, but I suppose you could go into django-registration (registration.auth_urls.py) and edit the login url so that it is r'^$' instead of r'^login/$'.  This generally isn't the best practice, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your actual www.example.com to be login page just do this:

```
url(r'^$', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

If you want your login page have its own page then do this:

```
url(r'^/login/$', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

So when you go to www.example.com/login it will go to login page.